# DBF to geoserver

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, dbf

I have a table as DBF.I would like to add the DBF to geoserver.I know we can publish a postgres table to geoserver. But i would like to know is there any way to add a DBF directly to geoserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - there is no way to push just a `dbf` file to GeoServer. The easiest way to do it would be to open the file in OpenOffice or Excel and save it as `CSV` format. Then add the **unsupported** community [`csv-datastore`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/unsupported/csv.html) to your GeoServer `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Comment: I could see the csv plugin form https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/unsupported. I would like to know where to add and what to add to enable this specific plugin?I mean i cant find the jar file.Is there any direct link to download the jar file?Am new to geoserver.

Comment: just drop the jar files into WEB-INF/lib

Comment: as it is unsupported you will need to build it your self

Comment: Well Alright...

Comment: I had downloaded the gt-csv jar from http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/org/geotools/gt-csv/14.4/ and pasted it in var/libs/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/webinf/libs and restarted my tomcat by sudo systemctl restart apache2.service. But i could not see anything in stores. Is there any dependency jar to be installed or what would be the problem?

Comment: Looks like you need net.sourceforge.javacsv:javacsv:jar:2.0  also check that your geoserver is built using version 14.4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42702/discussion-between-farook-and-iant).